# AWS Application load balancer: 503 gateway timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-elb

i would like to run my AWS fargate tasks in my Application Load balancer. But I get the 503 error when i run the DNS link. I go to my target groups and it tells me they are all draining.
When i go to the ECS task and take a look at services I see this:

```
86d61354-e714-412f-b62a-d15f59838ad8
2021-06-28 12:22:26 +0200
service AlbumService registered 1 targets in target-group newTargetGroupALBUMCONTAINER
66a03fab-a773-4a99-a6de-7c0d685dd739
2021-06-28 12:22:04 +0200
service AlbumService has started 1 tasks: task 8e730498b49d470681c725e6b9c08b5b.
7954f36a-25b2-4b31-979f-5c09b6136a52
2021-06-28 12:21:53 +0200
service AlbumService has started 1 tasks: task f86896d0855e4ed7912f352ccd554b77.
81646b25-828e-4677-a230-f7010e8f46a0
2021-06-28 12:21:52 +0200
service AlbumService deregistered 1 targets in target-group newTargetGroupALBUMCONTAINER
68229018-7137-49ca-bad7-83e6d97d7839
2021-06-28 12:21:43 +0200
service AlbumService has begun draining connections on 1 tasks.
d4b225c4-1880-48d9-b088-259d8447f7e2
2021-06-28 12:21:43 +0200
service AlbumService deregistered 1 targets in target-group newTargetGroupALBUMCONTAINER
93de0f96-4bfb-466b-86e6-8a5593f23513
2021-06-28 12:21:30 +0200
service AlbumService registered 1 targets in target-group newTargetGroupALBUMCONTAINER
95171356-ad5b-403c-89e3-189ed3532710
2021-06-28 12:20:58 +0200
service AlbumService has started 2 tasks: task f4c317be4de04ac28318998772ff8860 task
```

[ECS service setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkPJl.png)

This is my ALB configuration

```
Basic Configuration
Namealb-album
ARNarn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:107600463818:loadbalancer/app/alb-album/60a55e7dcc8e5b46 
DNS namealb-album-636293737.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com 
(A Record)
StateActive
Typeapplication
Schemeinternet-facing
IP address type
ipv4
Edit IP address type
VPCvpc-6a820b17 
Availability Zones
subnet-1580b71b - us-east-1f 
IPv4 address: Assigned by AWS

subnet-22c6cb6f - us-east-1b 
IPv4 address: Assigned by AWS

subnet-25e29a04 - us-east-1a 
IPv4 address: Assigned by AWS

subnet-5c9de303 - us-east-1c 
IPv4 address: Assigned by AWS

subnet-68a4d90e - us-east-1d 
IPv4 address: Assigned by AWS

subnet-941a9ba5 - us-east-1e 
IPv4 address: Assigned by AWS
Edit subnets
Hosted zoneZ35SXDOTRQ7X7K
Creation timeJune 27, 2021 at 5:08:43 PM UTC+2
Security
Security groups
sg-060e60bd68692ddba, sgalb-album
security
Edit security groups
Attributes
Deletion protection
Disabled
Idle timeout
60 seconds
HTTP/2
Enabled
Desync mitigation mode
Defensive
Drop invalid header fields
Disabled
Access logs
Disabled
WAF fail open
Disabled
```

[Inbound rules of my ALB security group:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZIcB.png)
[Outbound rules of my ALB security group:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBXGC.png)

[Target group:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUIsL.png)

For some reason I see more and more targets being added. I don't know why. I never registered any. (maybe this is normal that they get registered by itself but I have no idea)

Comment: You have to provide exact setup of your ecs service, load balancer, target group and vpc

Comment: Hey I added the extra information, if i provided the incorrect info let me know

Comment: It looks like the service is not stabilising because it's not passing the ELB health check. What is health check value set to?

Comment: I have a similar problem. I am able to access the 3001 port through public IP of ec2, but, when I try to access through a domain(configure to the load balancer in Route53), it gives me 503 error. Were you able to solve this? I posted the similar question too.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your configurations, the issue must be with the security group of the service `AlbumService`. I highly suspect the load balancer **do not have access** on the service `AlbumService` which is causing the health check to fail on the target group.

So you will have to allow inbound traffic from the load balancer to your service named `AlbumService`. Usually this will done by updating the security group of your service `AlbumService` to allow traffic from the security group of the load balancer.